# Use different file for bot commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to keep my code clean looking and easier to understand, by putting all the longer stuff in another file. I have my main file (index.js):

```
 const discord = require('discord.js');
 require('dotenv').config()

 const token = process.env.botToken;
 const prefix = "s!";

 const cmds = require("./commands.js");

 var client = new discord.Client();

 client.on('ready', function(message) {});

 client.on('message', function(message) {
    if(message.author.equals(client.user) || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    var args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0].toLowerCase()) {
        case "help":
            cmds.help;
            break;
    }
 });

 client.login(token)
```

and my other folder (commands.js):

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
var client = new discord.Client();

    module.exports = {
        help: function(message) {
            var embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
                .addField("spyBot Commands", "If you get issues, dont be afraid to join us: http://discord.gg/3k6zGNF");
            message.channel.send(embed);
        }
    }
```

I would like it to send the embed, but when I put the command in, nothing happens and no errors are printed.

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/#/command-handling/ and https://discordjs.guide/#/command-handling/dynamic-commands

Comment: I would personally recommend discord.js-commando for organized code.

Answer (score 1):

I see two major things that need to be fixed:
**1**: the client in *commands.js*
**2**: the command function in the main file

**1** - In *commands.js*, you created a new client. If you have only this command, it won't cause any problem since `client` is not used in your code, but when you'll need it that won't work since it has to be the same as in the main file. You have two possible solutions: setting your client as global or requiring the main module. If your bot doesn't have to be published in a public package then you can save `global.client = client;`, and then access it as `client` in every other file. The alternative is to export the client from the main module (`module.exports = {client};`) and then require the main file in *commands.js* (`var {client} = require("./index.js");`).

**2** - In *commands.js* you're exporting a `help` **function**, so when you call it *index.js* you have to use parenthesis and pass the message as an argument. Try something like this:

```
//in the switch statement
case "help":
  cmds.help(message);
  break;
```

I hope this can help you, let me know if you have any further question.