# Discord.js: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm creating bot with discord.js.
This is my code:

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
const swarmConfig = require('./swarmConfig.json');

var swarmbot = new Discord.Client();
swarmbot.login('myToken');

fs.readdir('./commands/', (err, files) =>{
  if(err) console.log(err);
  var jsFiles = files.filter(f => f.split('.').pop() === 'js');

  if(jsFiles.length <=0){
    console.log('Cant find commands');
    return;
  }

  jsFiles.forEach((f, i) =>{
    let fileGet = require(`./commands/${f}`);
    console.log(`${f} loaded!`);
    swarmbot.commands.set(fileGet.help.name, fileGet);
  });
});

swarmbot.on("message", async message =>{
  if (message.author.swarmbot) 
    return;
  var prefix = swarmConfig.prefix;
  var command = messageArray[0];
  var arguments = messageArray.slice(1);

  var commands = swarmbot.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length));
  if(commands) 
    commands.run(swarmbot, message, arguments);
});
```

But if I try to start it, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\purul\Desktop\swarm-dsbot\swarm.js:25
swarmbot.commands.set(fileGet.help.name, fileGet);
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
at jsFiles.forEach (C:\Users\purul\Desktop\swarm-dsbot\swarm.js:25:23)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at fs.readdir (C:\Users\purul\Desktop\swarm-dsbot\swarm.js:22:11)
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)
```

I'm still learning JavaScript, Thanks to everyone who will help with this.

Comment: The error means that the value `swarmbot` resolves to doesn't have a property `commands`.

Comment: My guess is that the error occurs because when you call this `swarmbot.login('myToken');` you meant to write `swarmbot.login(myToken);` (without the parentheses)

Comment: @SagiRika They most likely replaced their real token with myToken to not get their token stolen.

Comment: There are several problems here.  As Axium pointed out, Discord.Client has no "commands" member.  ALSO: I strong suggest using `const Discord = require('discord.js');`, instead of "var".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look in the documentation for Discord.js, there is no such object called 'commands'.
Link: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/search?q=commands
I'm guessing that you're loading them from a file, so you should maybe create a js file that has the commands, and load them to you main file.

Reference for possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51333277/7363404 (you should also check the question)